# Webdriver: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect

Tags: java, webdriver

While running webdriver, 3 minutes into running, I get the following exception and Webdriver crashes.

I am using only one webdriver instance and one FirefoxDriver profile.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1',
java.version: '1.6.0_18'
Driver info: driver.version: remote
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:
341)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:
234)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:
173)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:
231)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$6.findElements(By.java:200)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:
158)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:
123)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:
133)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:
149)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:
108)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:
415)
        at
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:
641)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:
211)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:
125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:341)
        at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:
328)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of where the problem is occurring from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebDriver: executeScript() causes BindException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330459/webdriver-executescript-causes-bindexception)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running out of outbound ports. That means you've performed thousands of outbound connections within two minutes. Solution: use a connection pool, or slow your program down.

Comment: I realized that running Javascript on each page loaded via WebDriver test `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javascripthere)` is causing this problem. However, I need to run Javascript on the pages being tested.

Comment: You do but you don't need to test an unrealistic situation. Practical clients won't open thousands of outbound connections. You're only doing that because you want to saturate the *server*. So the answer is to use more hardware clients.

Comment: not sure what you menat by connection pool. How do I close the outbound connections once they are finished being used ?

Comment: Not knowing anything about WebDriver I can't really answer that, but I would be looking for a close() or disconnect() method.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in a set of machines where some ran Win2003, some ran Windows7 and many ran Linux. What I found was that closing all the java processes and restarting helped a little, especially after running the java processes for many days on end.  And, what helped very significantly was [Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) with **MaxUserPort** of **10000** (twice the default of 5000) and **TcpTimedWaitDelay** of **30** (minimum) on the Win2003 machine which was running the standalone selenium grid as the hub role.   REBOOT after changing - per instructions on MSDN.

The Windows "netstat -b" command was very useful on the Win2003 machine in order to confirm that dozens and dozens of tcp/ip connections were open (ports 4444 and 5555); those were quite obviously part of the Selenium Grid (v2) system.

In Java, I use driver.quit(); at the end of each test method. I tried driver.close() and lost the ability to run more than one test in a row.

I can now run 250 tests with 0 exceptions showing up on the Hub's java console.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is like mine, where you

> 1. open port 1
> 2. connect to machine
> 3. ??
> 4. close port 1
> 5. open port 1
> 6. connect to different machine

try adding `socket.setSoLinger(true, 0);`
directly before `socket.close();`.

Like so:

```
socket.setSoLinger(true, 0);
socket.close();
```

This forces the OS to release the socket, rather than putting it in a `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: It also forces TCP to discard any data in flight, and it also forces the peer to deal with an error ECONNRESET rather than a normal end of stream. Both of these are semantic changes to the application. Not recommended.