# Selenium Webdriver: INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when connecting to the target host: Address already in use: connect

Tags: java, webdriver

Im running a Selenium Webdriver with Java/TestNG automated user registration at my website.
Reading from CSV

First, I open a Firefox with a certain profile
Then I have a loop and in it I create a user and sign them out, and go to the signup page again and register another user, log them out etc.

It is all working, but I get these red warnings and I do not know what  are  they related to:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when connecting to the target host:
Address already in use: connect
```

I understood now, thanks to the answer below, that I probably need to close() or disconnect() some connections, but which ones?

This snippet of code is what I do once:

```
 public void setUp(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) throws Exception {
     long timeoutInSeconds = 30;
     ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
     FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds );
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     userSignup(array, driver, wait);
```

and this is what I loop through:

```
        driver.get("http://asd.asd.com/users/sign_up");
```

and there is also an open connection to a CSV file reader, but at the end of the method, after passing an array of data, I close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320397/webdriver-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-connect) question solves this problem

It's the info-level message. Don't worry about it.

Comment: so do I have to close() or disconnect() something? I have edited my info

Comment: I thing it's something wrong with your selenium server. Which version are you using?

Comment: Im using the 2.32 version. 2.33 has some problems with firefox. How do I set the 4444 port?