# Selenium - Address already in use: connect

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, jsoup

I am trying to crawl and parse a dynamic content of website using selenium,
Generally the website am crawling loads its content by the scroll event from the page,So i triggered the scroll event by selenium until the end of the page is reached.

In Product phase am fetching each product detail by loop iteration, it also works fine.. but when it reaches iteration count of 280 above....

This is my code below...

```
private void init() throws IOException {

            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();//Create Firefox profile
            profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", true);//Allow javascript for browser
            WebDriver htmDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);//add profile to firefoxDriver


            htmDriver.get(urlTextField.getText());//Get and Connect to the url from URL text Field 
            htmDriver.manage().window().maximize();//Maximize the Browser window

            String count = htmDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#numbFound > #no-of-results-filter")).getText();//Total Product Count for the category
            //System.out.println("Total Category Count : "+count);      

            htmDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".list")).click();//Click to view the Product in List 
            htmDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Wait

            int lCount = Integer.parseInt(count);//Calculate the scroll length

            for (int i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(lCount / 5); i++) {

                //Generate Arrow Down Action
                htmDriver.findElement(By.id("products-main4")).sendKeys(
                        Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                htmDriver.findElement(By.id("products-main4")).sendKeys(
                        Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                htmDriver.findElement(By.id("products-main4")).sendKeys(
                        Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                htmDriver.findElement(By.id("products-main4")).sendKeys(

                ((JavascriptExecutor) htmDriver).executeScript(
                        "window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)", "");           

                htmDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            }

    //Product Phase
            int row2 = 0;
            List<WebElement> rdata = htmDriver.findElements(By.className("product_list_view_cont"));//selector to select each product row

            for (WebElement data : rdata) {


                String title = data.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product_list_view_heading")).getText();//Get Product Title

                System.out.println(title);

                //Check if Product Price available
                boolean product_price = data.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product_list_view_price_outer span")).isEmpty();

                if(product_price == false){

                //Get the Price of the Product
                String price = data.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product_list_view_price_outer var[id^=selling-price-id-]")).getText().trim();
                    System.out.println(price);

                }else{
                    //If Price not Available add make the data null

                    system.out.println("No price")
                }           


                String brand = data.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.key-features li")).getText();            
                System.out.println(brand);


                String brandUrl =  data.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product_list_view_info_cont a")).getAttribute("href");//Fetch Brand Url 
                    System.out.println(brandUrl);


                String status =  data.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product_list_view_buy-outer .lfloat")).getText();//Fetch Brand Url 
                    System.out.println(status);

            }
        }
```

selenium throws exception as follows

```
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:10 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:7055: Address already in use: connect
Feb 18, 2015 10:00:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:7055
```

for each Iteration after some times...

Comment: Please see the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320397/webdriver-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-connect) that explains that.

Comment: You've tested to change the port 7055 to 8081 or any other? The 7055 port must be in use by another service and so the message "Address already in use". I hope this helps!